# Given vectors X and Y, compute array C such that C[i, j] = 1 / (x[i] - y[j])

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I tried to solve this problem with the loop but in my case performance also matters. So, is there any way to solve this with numpy built in function?

Here the code that I tried:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 20)

C = np.arange(100).reshape(10,20)

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(20):
        C[i, j] = 1 / (x[i] - y[j])

print(C)
```

Comment: do `x` and `y` have different number of elements always? Why `C` is defined as 10 by 10?

Comment: Yeah! that's the problem x and y both are different.

Comment: Why is `C` initialed to (10,10), while `y` has 20 elements?  Why not `C = np.zeros((10,20))`?  And loop `j` over `range(20)`.  As my answer shows, initialling `C` as you do, creates problems with both shape and `dtype`.

Comment: Actually, I used the both 10 and with 20 both doesn't work for me.

Comment: provide a valid mathematical definition of a subtraction between two vectors of different lengths. Once you do that then the problem will be solved. Perhaps you want a 10 by 20 vector as mentioned above. What you are trying to do is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [158]: np.random.seed(123) 
     ...: x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10) 
     ...: y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 20) 
     ...:  
     ...: C = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10) 
     ...:  
     ...: for i in range(10): 
     ...:     for j in range(10): 
     ...:         C[i, j] = 1 / (x[i] - y[j]) 
     ...:
```

A no-loop version is:

```
In [159]: np.allclose(1/(x[:,None]-y[None,:]),C)                                                             
...
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,20) (10,10)
```

Oops, the calculation works, but produces a (10,20) array, were as you created a (10,10) by only looping on part of `y`:

```
In [160]: np.allclose(1/(x[:,None]-y[None,:10]),C)                                                           
Out[160]: False
```

But why don't they match?  Let's check the values:

```
In [161]: C                                                                                                  
Out[161]: 
array([[   2,  -30,    3,    1,    3,  -24,    1,    1,    6,    6],
       [ -17,   -2,   -6,    4,   -8,   -2,    9,    9,   -4,   -4],
       [  -8,   -1,   -4,    5,   -5,   -1,   22,   19,   -3,   -3],
       [   4,   -5,    8,    2,    6,   -5,    2,    2,   50,   51],
       [   2, -104,    3,    1,    3,  -53,    1,    1,    5,    5],
       [  12,   -3,  -64,    2,   39,   -3,    4,    4,   -9,   -9],
       [   1,    3,    1,    1,    1,    4,    1,    1,    2,    2],
       [   2,  -22,    4,    1,    3,  -18,    1,    1,    6,    6],
       [   7,   -4,   23,    2,   12,   -3,    3,    3,  -19,  -19],
       [  20,   -2,  -21,    3, -168,   -2,    4,    4,   -7,   -7]])
In [162]: 1/(x[:,None]-y[None,:10])                                                                          
Out[162]: 
array([[   2.83052645,  -30.69318553,    3.87751788,    1.57037324,
           3.35092648,  -24.08117081,    1.94561063,    1.91932159,
           6.06362642,    6.07379914],
       [ -17.53196215,   -2.25779314,   -6.56026315,    4.41576282,
          -8.93615756,   -2.21309409,    9.64807633,    9.03443739,
          -4.07477972,   -4.07019868],
       [  -8.59648887,   -1.99124547,   -4.7232017 ,    5.98180728,
          -5.8413671 ,   -1.95639603,   22.54297209,   19.45536745,
          -3.2819175 ,   -3.2789451 ],
       [   4.80453349,   -5.62635579,    8.86976769,    2.03402156,
           6.52441214,   -5.35674196,    2.71132737,    2.66054378,
          50.5985934 ,   51.31578289],
       [   2.65751805, -104.37609732,    3.56002726,    1.5156313 ,
           3.11114844,  -53.97692265,    1.86227633,    1.83817713,
           5.32148144,    5.32931481],
       [  12.51119064,   -3.26858007,  -64.65886011,    2.75157239,
          39.90071936,   -3.17572279,    4.15602154,    4.0378801 ,
          -9.22127157,   -9.19784432],
       [   1.56841542,    3.97275499,    1.84436525,    1.0856746 ,
           1.71609023,    4.11914558,    1.25270511,    1.24175407,
           2.22611632,    2.22748596],
       [   2.92695729,  -22.61421767,    4.06079013,    1.59961138,
           3.48692684,  -18.80913104,    1.99069149,    1.96317869,
           6.52407795,    6.53585581],
       [   7.25932338,   -4.03034356,   23.60736785,    2.37386467,
          12.06452404,   -3.89008935,    3.35075535,    3.27353517,
         -19.75524346,  -19.64803083],
       [  20.4333914 ,   -2.96795626,  -21.5263349 ,    3.00806503,
        -168.72690268,   -2.89119379,    4.77040545,    4.61540389,
          -7.17185934,   -7.15768024]])
```

`C` was initialed as integer dtype, so truncates any float values that are inserted.  We can get the same effect with:

```
In [163]: (1/(x[:,None]-y[None,:10])).astype(int)                                                            
Out[163]: 
array([[   2,  -30,    3,    1,    3,  -24,    1,    1,    6,    6],
       [ -17,   -2,   -6,    4,   -8,   -2,    9,    9,   -4,   -4],
       [  -8,   -1,   -4,    5,   -5,   -1,   22,   19,   -3,   -3],
       [   4,   -5,    8,    2,    6,   -5,    2,    2,   50,   51],
       [   2, -104,    3,    1,    3,  -53,    1,    1,    5,    5],
       [  12,   -3,  -64,    2,   39,   -3,    4,    4,   -9,   -9],
       [   1,    3,    1,    1,    1,    4,    1,    1,    2,    2],
       [   2,  -22,    4,    1,    3,  -18,    1,    1,    6,    6],
       [   7,   -4,   23,    2,   12,   -3,    3,    3,  -19,  -19],
       [  20,   -2,  -21,    3, -168,   -2,    4,    4,   -7,   -7]])
```

Now they match:

```
In [164]: np.allclose((1/(x[:,None]-y[None,:10])).astype(int),C)                                             
Out[164]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this method [`fromfunction`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) that should do what you want.

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 20)

# for a 10 by 20 array
C = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: 1/(x[i] - y[j]), (10, 20), dtype=int)

# for a 10 by 10 array
C = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: 1/(x[i] - y[j]), (10, 10), dtype=int)

# to avoid defining the shape
C = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: 1/(x[i] - y[j]), (x.size, y.size), dtype=int)
```

If you want to make this all integers then just do `C.astype(int)` etc.

Answer (score -1):

- This solution works under some assumptions.
- assuming x and y are 1D vectors only. They may have different size.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 20)

# C = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
ln = min(x.shape[0], y.shape[0])

# this will get rid of manually defining C shape. Also works for any length of 1D x and y
C = np.reciprocal(1/(x - y.reshape((-1,1))))

# or you can also just simply do
C = 1/(x - y.reshape((-1,1)))
```